# Scripting Eclipse .. or alternatives

Tags: java, android, eclipse, scripting

I have written an android application.  I would like to be able to customize the app programmatically.  For example, change logos/titles within the application.

Assume I have a simple web server that displays a form with fields to input text, upload images etc.  Upon submission of this form, I would like to generate an apk file available for download for the user.

Is there a way to script eclipse to achieve this?  Is that even where I should be looking?  If anyone has done something like this, (or have some ideas), please let me know!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to script eclipse to achieve this?

Possibly, but I doubt it.

> Is that even where I should be looking?

[Use Ant](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html). Make a copy of some master project, make your adjustments from the entered data, and run the appropriate `ant` tasks (e.g., `ant release build`) to create the APK.

Answer (score 0):

We have put together a system that creates multiple, customised APKs from a single body of source code. The system is not in a state where we can make it available (although we may open source it at some point) but the general structure is described [here](http://www.swiftkey.net/building-apks-with-different-features-from-a-single-source).

Having said that, the system you describe in your question is much more dynamic than what we need. We only need to create a few (~10) different variants. It strikes me that what you're trying to do would be better solved by having a single APK together with a configuration file. Your webserver would generate the configuration file, not the APK.

Comment: Interesting idea.  One issue is that the web form includes image uploads.  Perhaps the config file could link to URLs that the app downloads and saves upon installation.